# how to select the list item of a unordered list uniquely without assigning unique id to each list item

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
 <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="list-item">
            <div class="list-item-container">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <div class="item-highlighter"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
            <div class="list-item-container">
                <a href="#">Find</a>
                <div class="item-highlighter"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
            <div class="list-item-container">
                <a href="#">Sell</a>
                <div class="item-highlighter"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
            <div class="list-item-container">
                <a href="#">Help</a>
                <div class="item-highlighter"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
            <div class="list-item-container">
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                <div class="item-highlighter"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

here is my code all I want is when I click on any list item, it should change the color of that very li's div with id='item-highlighter'. And this should be done using jquery only ... thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also you can do this in JavaScript, jQuery is not required.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/closest

Comment: You can use https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: I want to add this code to my navbar and the functionality I want is that whenever I click any of list item it gets underlined by filling the color to the div with id item-highlighter and i want to do it with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use an event listener on click using the .on() method

```
$( ".nav-links" ).on( "click", "li", function() {
    $('div.list-item-container', this).attr('id', 'item-highlighter');
});
```

```js
$( ".nav-links" ).on( "click", "li", function() {
    $('.nav-links li div').removeAttr('id');
    $('div.list-item-container', this).attr('id', 'item-highlighter');
});
```

```css
#item-highlighter{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="list-item">
            <div class="list-item-container">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <div class="item-highlighter"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
            <div class="list-item-container">
                <a href="#">Find</a>
                <div class="item-highlighter"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
            <div class="list-item-container">
                <a href="#">Sell</a>
                <div class="item-highlighter"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
            <div class="list-item-container">
                <a href="#">Help</a>
                <div class="item-highlighter"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
            <div class="list-item-container">
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                <div class="item-highlighter"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: tried but didn't worked

Comment: @AryanChoudhary It seems to work tho, check my snippet

Comment: @AryanChoudhary  I suppose you want to un-light the other div when you click on other li, so I added this line as well `$('.nav-links li div').removeAttr('id');`